# How to get the last column index reading excel file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

How do i get the index of the last column when reading a `xlsx` file using the Apache POI API?

There's a `getLastRowNum` method, but I can't find nothing related to the number of columns...

EDIT:
I'm dealing with `XLSX` files

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you'll have to iterate through the rows and check [`HSSFRow.getLastCellNum()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getLastCellNum--) on each of them.

Comment: For XLSX files the only thing you have to change is HSSF to XSSF.
XSSFRow.getLastCellNum()

Answer (score 14):

Check each Row and call `Row.getLastCellNum()` the max cell number is the last column number.

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
int maxCell=  r.getLastCellNum();
```

Answer (score 6):

To get to know the last column that has value of any row , First you need to get the row and then you can find the last column that has value

Syntax :

```
sheet.getrow(RowNumber).getLastCellNum();
```

`RowNumber` --> is the row number for which you want to know the last column that has value

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
private void maxExcelrowcol() {
    int row, col, maxrow, maxcol;

    //Put file name here for example filename.xls
    String filename = "filename.xls";
    static String TAG = "ExelLog";

    //you can use 'this' in place of context if you want
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    try {
        // Creating Input Stream
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

        // Create a workbook using the File System
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Row iterator 
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            //Cell iterator for iterating from cell to next cell of a row
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();

                row = myCell.getRowIndex();
                col = myCell.getColumnIndex();

                if (maxrow < row) {
                    maxrow = row;
                }
                if (maxcol < col) {
                    maxcol = col;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you would also add a few comments to your code. This helps people to understand your answer better.